# Encode video using ffmpeg and vp8 codec on Native Client

Tags: ffmpeg, google-nativeclient

I'm trying to develop a video encoder using Native Client.
I want the output file to be .webm and I'm using ffmpeg example "muxing.c".

When I run the example I get the error message: Could not find encoder for 'vp8'

The error comes from here:

```
*codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
if (!(*codec)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n",
            avcodec_get_name(codec_id));
}
```

Where `codec_id` value is `AV_CODEC_ID_VP8`

When I put the output file to be .mp4 it works.

Can someone help me.
Do I need to enable vp8 encoder for ffmpeg naclport?
What should I do?

Thanks!!

### UPDATE

@Lee Gi Gone:

> Yes. you must need to compile ffmpeg with libvpx library to encode
>   vp8/vp9. you can install it via yum, apt. or you can compile it
>   manually.
>
> Once libvpx is installed, install ffmpeg with libvpx in following
>   command :
>
> ```
> ./configure --enable-libvpx 
> make -j 4
> make install
> ```

I put the dependency for libvpx on build.sh and pkg_info on ffmpeg naclport and built it again. Now it works!

Comment: Hi Victor, I am interested to see the result you got, I want to develop a screen recorder that makes a video out of the desktop in chrome then upload the video to youtube. I have no idea how it is done. I hope you can provide me some sample code to see how is ti done

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you must need to compile ffmpeg with libvpx library to encode vp8/vp9. you can install it via yum, apt. or you can compile it manually.

Once libvpx is installed, install ffmpeg with libvpx in following command :

```
./configure --enable-libvpx
make -j 4
make install
```

Comment: Because I was using ffmpeg in nacl I had to do it in other way. I just added the dependency for libvpx on build.sh and pkg_info and built ffmpeg naclport again. Thanks!